# Ajax.BeginForm returning to new page and not HTML DIV in Visual Studio

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I cannot get this form to come back with a simple string displayed in the component, instead it writes to a new page.

The code is here, and I am new to this, but it seems to be following the guidelines I read?  I have tried this with the div outside of the list on its on, and also wrapping the list objects as it shows here.

Any ideas, it's driving me mad.

It is returning a search string from postGreSQL, but does display it all correctly on the new page, just not in the div I want it to.

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    }

    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
        <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Find Address</legend>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Display", "Home",
                                        new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                                            UpdateTargetId = "divAddressSearchResults"
                                        }))
        {
            <div id="divAddressSearchResults">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Label("House Number")
                        @Html.TextBox("_HouseNumber", "", new { @style = "text-transform:uppercase" })
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Label("House Name")
                        @Html.TextBox("_HouseName", "", new { @style = "text-transform:uppercase" })
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Label("Post Code")
                        @Html.TextBox("_PostCode", "", new { @style = "text-transform:uppercase" })
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <button>Search</button>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` in your project?

Comment: I do, sorry, I'll add the code that I missed out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't loading a library properly, I am remote working and I think there's been some network outage.  It's working properly now.  It was hard to spot as it was inconsistent, in that I had to load the library when they was an outage....

Thanks